Pytorch custom Env Reinforcement Learning How to make it work?
I'm quite new to reinforcement learning in general and with pytorch. I tried do a simulation in unity where a Ball is thrown upwards. Within a small delay (350ms) a robot with a gripper is ment to catch the ball. For each input (ball-startspeed and ball-startangle) the RL-agent is ment to find the fastest time to catch the ball. (Sometimes the robot wont be fast enough at the target position).
My problem now with my code is that I can iterate over the environment with the loop below, but I can see no learning process and the action is still taken randomly after 20_000 iterations. I suspect the problem is within my training loop, but I have no clue how to fix it. Also I defined my action as a BoundedTensor (low=0.2 high=0.8) but I get actionvalues that are out of those boundaries.
I tried to stick to the tutorial on the pytorch website.(https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/pendulum.html#)
The first number is the ball start speed, the second one the angle, and the third is the action.
VS Code Outputs
import gymnasium as gym
import math
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple, deque
from itertools import count
import io

from torchrl.collectors import SyncDataCollector
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tensordict.nn.distributions import NormalParamExtractor

from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Optional

import numpy as np
import tqdm
from tensordict import TensorDict, TensorDictBase
from tensordict.nn import TensorDictModule
from torch import nn

from torchrl.data import BoundedTensorSpec, CompositeSpec, UnboundedContinuousTensorSpec
from torchrl.envs import (
    CatTensors,
    EnvBase,
    Transform,
    TransformedEnv,
    UnsqueezeTransform,
)
from torchrl.envs import (Compose, DoubleToFloat, ObservationNorm, StepCounter,
                          TransformedEnv)
is_ipython = 'inline' in matplotlib.get_backend()
if is_ipython:
    from IPython import display
from torchrl.envs.transforms.transforms import _apply_to_composite
from torchrl.envs.utils import check_env_specs, step_mdp
import socket
from torchrl.modules import ProbabilisticActor, TanhNormal, ValueOperator
    
HOST = "127.0.0.1" # Local
PORT = 40000

device = "cpu"

plt.ion()

Transition = namedtuple('Transition',
                        ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward'))


class ReplayMemory(object):

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.memory = deque([], maxlen=capacity)

    def push(self, *args):
        """Save a transition"""
        self.memory.append(Transition(*args))

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)
    
class DQN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_observations, n_actions):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(n_observations, 128)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(128, n_actions)

    # Called with either one element to determine next action, or a batch
    # during optimization. Returns tensor([[left0exp,right0exp]...]).
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer2(x))
        return self.layer3(x)

def _make_spec(self):
    self.observation_spec = CompositeSpec(
        speed=BoundedTensorSpec(
            low=2.0,
            high=4.0,
            shape=(),
            dtype=torch.float32,
        ),
        angle=BoundedTensorSpec(
            low=-5.0,
            high=5.0,
            shape=(),
            dtype=torch.float32,
        ),
        observation=BoundedTensorSpec(
            low=[2.0, -5.0],
            high=[4.0, 5.0],
            shape=(2,),
            dtype=torch.float32,
        )
    )
    self.action_spec = BoundedTensorSpec(
        low=[0.2],
        high=[0.8],
        shape=(1,),  # Single scalar action
        dtype=torch.float32,
    )
    self.state_spec = self.observation_spec.clone()
    self.reward_spec = UnboundedContinuousTensorSpec(shape=(1,))

def _set_seed(self, seed: Optional[int]):
    rng = torch.manual_seed(seed)
    self.rng = rng
       
def _step(tensordict):
    
    speed, angle, action, observe = tensordict["speed"], tensordict["angle"], tensordict["action"], tensordict["observation"]
    
    sendstring = str(speed.item())
    sendstring += " "
    sendstring += str(angle.item())
    sendstring += " "
    sendstring += str(action.item())
    
    print(sendstring)
    
    bytesend = sendstring.encode()
    conn.sendall(bytesend)
    data = conn.recv(1024) 
    data = data.decode('utf-8')   
    
    if data == "1":        
        reward = 1.0 + (10.0 - 10.0 * abs(action.item()))   # Ball is caught and emphathize early catches
        print("Caught ball")
    elif data == "0":
        reward = -1.0 - (10.0*abs(action.item()))
        print("No Ball")
    else:
        reward = -10.0

    done = True
    
    out = TensorDict(
        {
            "speed": speed,
            "angle": angle,
            "observation" : observe,
            "reward": reward,
            "done": done,
        },
        tensordict.shape,
    )
    return out

def _reset(self, tensordict):
    high_speed = torch.tensor(4.0, device=self.device)
    high_angle = torch.tensor(5.0, device=self.device)
    low_speed = torch.tensor(2.0, device=self.device)
    low_angle = -high_angle

    # Define a default shape if tensordict is None
    if tensordict is None:
        batch_size = ()
    else:
        batch_size = tensordict.shape

    # # Generate random speed and angle within the specified ranges
    speed = torch.rand(batch_size, device=self.device) * (high_speed - low_speed) + low_speed
    angle = torch.rand(batch_size, device=self.device) * (high_angle - low_angle) + low_angle
    
    # speed = torch.rand(tensordict.shape, generator=self.rng, device=self.device)* (high_speed - low_speed)+ low_speed
    # angle = torch.rand(tensordict.shape, generator=self.rng, device=self.device)* (high_angle - low_angle)+ low_angle
    
    observe = torch.tensor([speed, angle])
    # Create the observation tensor
    observation = TensorDict(
        {
            "speed": speed,
            "angle": angle,
            "observation" : observe
        }
    )
    return observation
    
class BallEnv(EnvBase):
    batch_locked = False

    def __init__(self, seed=None, device="cpu"):

        super().__init__(device=device, batch_size=[])
        self._make_spec()
        if seed is None:
            seed = torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_().item()
        self.set_seed(seed)

    # Helpers: _make_step and gen_params
    _make_spec = _make_spec

    # Mandatory methods: _step, _reset and _set_seed
    _reset = _reset
    _step = staticmethod(_step)
    _set_seed = _set_seed

def _reset(self, tensordict):
    high_speed = torch.tensor(4.0, device=self.device)
    high_angle = torch.tensor(5.0, device=self.device)
    low_speed = torch.tensor(2.0, device=self.device)
    low_angle = -high_angle

    # Define a default shape if tensordict is None
    if tensordict is None:
        batch_size = ()
    else:
        batch_size = tensordict.shape

    # # Generate random speed and angle within the specified ranges
    speed = torch.rand(batch_size, device=self.device) * (high_speed - low_speed) + low_speed
    angle = torch.rand(batch_size, device=self.device) * (high_angle - low_angle) + low_angle
    
    # speed = torch.rand(tensordict.shape, generator=self.rng, device=self.device)* (high_speed - low_speed)+ low_speed
    # angle = torch.rand(tensordict.shape, generator=self.rng, device=self.device)* (high_angle - low_angle)+ low_angle
    
    observe = torch.tensor([speed, angle])
    # Create the observation tensor
    observation = TensorDict(
        {
            "speed": speed,
            "angle": angle,
            "observation" : observe
        }
    )
    return observation
    
class BallEnv(EnvBase):
    batch_locked = False

    def __init__(self, seed=None, device="cpu"):

        super().__init__(device=device, batch_size=[])
        self._make_spec()
        if seed is None:
            seed = torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_().item()
        self.set_seed(seed)

    # Helpers: _make_step and gen_params
    _make_spec = _make_spec

    # Mandatory methods: _step, _reset and _set_seed
    _reset = _reset
    _step = staticmethod(_step)
    _set_seed = _set_seed
    
env = BallEnv(seed=1)
print("Verbindung zu unity herstellen")
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))            
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
                    
check_env_specs(env)

torch.manual_seed(0)
env.set_seed(0)

net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(2, 16),
    nn.Linear(16, 32),
    nn.Linear(32, 1),
)
policy = TensorDictModule(
    net,
    in_keys=["observation"],
    out_keys=["action"],
)

optim = torch.optim.Adam(policy.parameters(), lr=2e-3)

batch_size = 1
pbar = tqdm.tqdm(range(20_000 // batch_size))
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optim, 20_000)
logs = defaultdict(list)

for _ in pbar:
    init_td = env.reset()
    rollout = env.rollout(100, policy, tensordict=init_td, auto_reset=False)
    traj_return = rollout["next", "reward"].mean()
    gn = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), 1.0)
    optim.step()
    optim.zero_grad()
    pbar.set_description(
        f"reward: {traj_return: 4.4f}, "
        f"last reward: {rollout[..., -1]['next', 'reward'].mean(): 4.4f}, gradient norm: {gn: 4.4}"
    )
    logs["return"].append(traj_return.item())
    logs["last_reward"].append(rollout[..., -1]["next", "reward"].mean().item())
    scheduler.step()

Sorry for the long code, but I think it helps the case.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
